# Selenium doesn't find element

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

My Selenium application throws an error when I try to test it, even when I think the XPath is correct and using an explicit wait, it just throws the 'Element not found error'.
Code:

```
string inputTextBoxXPath = "/html/body/div[@class='pages']/div[@class='main']/div[@class='game']/iframe/html/body/div[@class='main']/div[@class='bottom']/div[@class='round']/div[@class='selfTurn']/form/input[@class='styled']";
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement testIngame = wait.Until(e => e.FindElement(By.XPath(inputTextBoxXPath)));
```

Comment: please add additional information for *driver* what it returns, I mean *driver.get("your url");*

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't completely understand your request

Comment: look at the complete sample code, which provides what source document you are loading and what element you are looking for. From your example, we could only see the find element but we don't know from which document you are looking for that xpath https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/webdriverwait-selenium-webdriver/

Comment: @coder_b what I am doing is: driver first gets the website. Then a user needs to do some things in that browser, and after that he presses f10 which triggers a method with the code above

Answer (score 1):

I belive it's because of the iframe. You can't "xpath" into the iframe.

> This happens because Selenium is only aware of the elements in the top
> level document. [...] Switching using a WebElement is the most flexible option.
>
> ```
> //Store the web element
> WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#modal>iframe"));
>
> //Switch to the frame
> driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
>
> //Now we can click the button
> driver.findElement(By.tagName("button")).click();
> ```

Check this out: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/browser/frames